# watch command - handling quotes

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I'm trying to pass the following command to 'watch' in order to repeat the command periodically.

```
grep "foo bar" log_file.log | awk '$(NF-1) == 0'
```

However, when I do:

```
watch -n 5 "grep \"foo bar\" log_file.log | awk '$(NF-1) == 0'"
```

I get the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1:  == 0<br>
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ syntax error
```

How can I successfully pass this command to 'watch'?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the `$(NF-1)` expression. You need to escape the `$` so that it is interpreted within the `awk` command and not before, during the expansion:

```
watch -n 5 "grep \"foo bar\" log_file.log | awk '\$(NF-1) == 0'"
                                                 ^
```

Comment: You're welcome! Since you're new here, don't forget to mark the answer accepted whenever it helped (most) in understanding and solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 2):

I think your $ is being substituted.

watch -n 5 "grep 'foo bar' log_file.log | awk '\$(NF-1) == 0'"